# Create an atomic compare exchange instruction in LLVM-C

Tags: c, llvm, llvm-ir

Regarding the C interface for LLVM IR, the list of atomic operations don't seem to include the atomic compare exchange. In the C++ side, it's a class separate from the rest of the RMW ops. I can't find it anywhere in the C api, but I assume it has to be somewhere. What Build function do I need to use?

Comment: It's probably missing https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23354

Comment: Wow. That seems like a pretty critical omission. Thanks for the link.